# Matlab: How to unit test a Questdlg box?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, messagebox

I have this chunk of code which display a question box with three choices:

- Yes
- Save as
- No

I just want to create a unit test for each of those choices, and I need to interact with the box for it.
When the box is created, every matlab process is frozen until the user react. Of course my tests are automated, and there's no user present.

Is there a solution to send a "Yes" event to Matlab ?
I could use autoit but I would rather avoid that

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're best bet is to structure your code to not depend on the questdlg function directly but to wrap an interface around the function so that you can inject a test specific dependency, or "mock". This might look something like the following:

**Source Code Under Test**

```
function codeWhichUsesQuestDlg(dlgProvider)
validateattributes(dlgProvider, {'DialogProvider'},{});

if (needToAskQuestion)
    result = dlgProvider.provideQuestionDialog(...)
else
    ...
end
```

**Source Code Interface/Infrastructure**

```
classdef DialogProvider < handle
    methods(Abstract)
        result = provideQuestionDialog(varargin);
        % perhaps others? errordlg, etc?
    end
end
```

**Production Implementation**

```
classdef ProductionProvider < DialogProvider
    methods
        function result = provideQuestionDialog(varargin)
            result = questdlg(varargin{:}); 
        end
    end
end
```

**Production Usage**

```
>> codeWhichUsesQuestDlg(ProductionProvider)
```

**Test Usage**

```
classdef TestCode < matlab.mock.TestCase

    methods(Test)
        function testCode(testCase)
            % Create the test specific "mock" implementation
            [mockProvider, behavior] = testCase.createMock(?DialogProvider);

            % Define mock behavior needed for the test
            when(withAnyInputs(behavior.provideQuestionDialog), ...
                AssignOutputs('Yes'));

            % Call code under test with the mock
            codeWhichUsesQuestDlg(mockProvider);

            % Verify correct result/behavior
            ...
        end
    end
end
```

Take a look at the [mocking framework](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/mocking-framework.html) to see more info. Also you might be interested in [this post](https://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2017/07/06/dont-mock-me/) covering the mocking framework as well as [this post](https://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2016/02/24/dependency-injection/?s_tid=srchtitle) on dependency injection.

Comment: +1 Great example of a simple use of the mocking framework! May I suggest an edit to rename `mock` to `mockProvider`, to make it clearer what role that object is playing?

Comment: Thanks Sam. Nice suggestion, I've made the change.

Comment: This is a great example, unfortunately I do not have this framework available because my matlab is too old. We will soon move to more recent versions of matlab and I will make great use of this example when the time comes.

Comment: Hi Zangdar,

You can still structure your tests this way without a mocking framework, you just have to write the mock implementation by hand instead of using the framework to do it for you. That said, the mocking framework definitely makes it easy for you to do so.